# No level 2 and level 3 output in R package "dynamic"

Tags: r

I wish to compute the dynamic fit index cutoff values for a CFA model. However, my output does not show the values for the Level 2 and Level 3 misspecification.

Here is my code:

```
model <- '
f1 =~ item_1 + item_2 + item_3 + item_4 + item_5 + item_6 + item_7 + item_8 + item_9 + item_10 + item_11 + item_12 + item_13 + item_14
f2 =~ item_17 + item_18 + item_19 + item_20 + item_22 + item_23 + item_25 + item_27 + item_28
'

fit <- lavaan::cfa(model = model, data = data, estimator = "MLR") 
dfi <- cfaHB(fit)
print(dfi)
```

My output looks as follows:

```
Your DFI cutoffs: 
               SRMR RMSEA  CFI Magnitude
Level 1: 95/5  .036  .035 .981      .484
Level 1: 90/10   --    --   --          

Empirical fit indices: 
 Chi-Square  df p-value   SRMR   RMSEA    CFI
    886.474 229       0  0.061   0.091  0.869
```

I have the same when I use `print(dfi$cutoffs)`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Dan McNeish (co-author of the package) replied the following on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/dmcneish18/status/1635223193534488576): 

"Does your model have two factors? The current multi-factor version bases the number of levels on model size, and 2 factors only gives one level. 

We have a new algorithm in development that always gives 3 levels, regardless of model size. It should be released in a month or two"